# The system is running in low-graphics mode after installing

Tags: drivers, graphics

I have installed Ubuntu on a separate `ext4` partition. I did not create a `swap` partition, because I was going to create a swap file after installation. Ubuntu does not have an Internet connection, because I'm using a TP-LINK antenna.

I haven't changed any files or configuration files and I have about 50GB of storage space remaining in my Ubuntu partition.

On my first boot, I recieved the following error:

> **The system is running in low-graphics mode**
>
> Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.

If I attempt to login to a TTY, the session automatically closes after a short while (less than a second); but I **can** use the liveUSB and `chroot` my partition.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

while the system is booting hold shift to get to the grub menu then press E
it should bring up a bunch of text that you can navigate with the arrow keys
find the line that starts with linux
it should look similar to this
        `linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.5.0-rc3+ root=UUID=c9932a51-0d6a-4ed0-9098-2daafc9e4500 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff`
after "ro" add "nomodeset"
so the line should now look like this
    `linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.5.0-rc3+ root=UUID=c9932a51-0d6a-4ed0-9098-2daafc9e4500 ro nomodeset  quiet splash $vt_handoff`
then press F10
it may bring you to the login screen or may let you use TTY.